# Add an AND condition Where clause in query SQL

Tags: sql

let's take an example that i have a query like this  :

```
SELECT emp.resource_calendar_id, emp.name,rc.name, rcl.* from hr_employee emp
left join hr_department dep on dep.id = emp.department_id
left join hr_job job on job.id = emp.job_id
left join resource_calendar rc on emp.resource_calendar_id = rc.id
left join resource_calendar_attendance rcl on rcl.calendar_id = rc.id
```

and i want to add condition like this

```
if job.name == 'SECURITY':
  # add more condition in query
  where rcl.hour_from <= 18
  and rcl.hour_to >= 18
  and rcl.dayofweek = '6'
else job.name != 'SECURITY':
  #doesnt add any condition
```

the question is, how do i write that condition in sql query?

Comment: `left join resource_calendar_attendance rcl on rcl.calendar_id = rc.id and ( ( job.name = 'SECURITY' and <other conditions> ) or job.name != 'SECURITY' )`

Comment: Don't tag multiple SQL dialects without a reason. They often have very different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write this condition in `left join` and rearrange tables in join as follows:

```
SELECT emp.resource_calendar_id, emp.name,rc.name, rcl.* from hr_employee emp
left join hr_department dep on dep.id = emp.department_id
left join resource_calendar rc on emp.resource_calendar_id = rc.id
left join resource_calendar_attendance rcl on rcl.calendar_id = rc.id
left join hr_job job on job.id = emp.job_id 
      And (job.name != 'SECURITY'
           or  
            (rcl.hour_from <= 18
             and rcl.hour_to >= 18
             and rcl.dayofweek = '6') )
```

Note: I am considering that `job.name` is not null